# I'm using pyAMF in my app, but I want to set smart service like explained here:

Tags: python, pyamf

In a normal application i set services

```
services = {
    'users.login': login,
    'test': router
}
```

but I would like to do like this:

```
services = [
    'users.login',
    'test'
]
```

and every request goes to router function. this takes 2 params: service name (can be "users.login" or "test" in this case) and input (that is the object sent by flex to python)
then if the command(service) from flex is named "users.login". I would like to run the router with the params and then this will open the function login in the commands.users.login package. How would I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved last night!

```
from pyamf.remoting.gateway.google import WebAppGateway
import logging

class TottysGateway(WebAppGateway):
def __init__(self, services_available, root_path, not_found_service, logger, debug):
    # override the contructor and then call the super
    self.services_available = services_available
    self.root_path = root_path
    self.not_found_service = not_found_service
    WebAppGateway.__init__(self, {}, logger=logging, debug=True)

def getServiceRequest(self, request, target):
    # override the original getServiceRequest method
    try:
        # try looking for the service in the services list
        return WebAppGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        # don't know what it does but is an error for now
        service_func = self.router(target)
    except:
        if(target in self.services_available):
            # only if is an available service import it's module
            # so it doesn't access services that should be hidden
            try:
                module_path = self.root_path + '.' + target
                paths = target.rsplit('.')
                func_name = paths[len(paths) - 1]
                import_as = '_'.join(paths) + '_' + func_name
                import_string = "from "+module_path+" import "+func_name+' as service_func'
                exec import_string
            except:
                service_func = False

    if(not service_func):
        # if is not found load the default not found service
        module_path = self.rootPath + '.' + self.not_found_service
        import_string = "from "+module_path+" import "+func_name+' as service_func'

    # add the service loaded above
    assign_string = "self.addService(service_func, target)"
    exec assign_string

    return WebAppGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, in order to achieve this, you are going to need to to override `getServiceRequest` on the Gateway class that you are using:

```
from pyamf.remoting.gateway.django import DjangoGateway
from pyamf.remoting.gateway import UnknownServiceError


class MyGateway(DjangoGateway):
    def __init__(self, router_func, **kwargs):
        self.router = router_func

        DjangoGateway.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def getServiceRequest(self, request, target):
        try:
            return DjangoGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
        except UnknownServiceError, e:
            pass

        # cached service was not found, try to discover it
        try:
            service_func = self.router(target)
        except:
            # perhaps some logging here
            service_func = None

        if not service_func:
            # couldn't find a service matching `target`, crap out appropriately
            raise e

        self.addService(service_func, target)

        return DjangoGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
```

`self.router` is a function that you supply to the constructor of the gateway. It takes the string target of the AMF remoting request and returns a matching function. If it returns `None` or raises an exception, an unknown service response will be returned to the requestor.

Hopefully this goes some way to laying the groundwork for what you require.

Comment: Hey! i'm using the google, but i get it around how to do it. but it doesn't work as expected.
It must import the function from the package at runtime.
in case im requesting the 'a.b.c.d' command, i want to load the 'd' function from 'app.controllers.a.b.c.d' package and run it. is that possible?